# tensorflow doesn't work well with thrift

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I write a simple tensorflow code as follws:

```
class Classify():
    def __init__(self):
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,device_count = {'GPU': 0}) 
        self.sess = sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=session_conf)
        x = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
        a = tf.constant([3.0, 3.0])
        with sess.as_default():
        # Initialize 'x' using the run() method of its initializer op.
            x.initializer.run()

        # Add an op to subtract 'a' from 'x'.  Run it and print the result
            self.sub = tf.add(x, a)

    def clf(self, word):
        with self.sess.as_default():
            print 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            return self.sub.eval()
```

it works well when i drect create an obejct and call obj.clf.
But when i use thrift, i create obj in server end, and use thrift API to call to make server run obj.clf. it first return error

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1296] failed to enqueue          
async memcpy from host to device: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED; GPU dst:
0x2305ba0700; host src: 0x2048a0000; size: 8=0x8
```

when i reproduce some nums of this  error, they after always blocks dead when i call thrift client.

Any one work well with thrift&tensorflow?

Comment: Thrift version 0.9.1; Tensorflow version 1.0.0

Comment: I can't fugure out why they work differnetly when direct all or thrift client call, i make it run on cpu, cpu memory is enough. How can i figure out what the code is when server block??